# ERROR!!! API version is not found in installed Android SDK: 2.1

Tags: android, ruby, rhomobile

I am starting Android development in Ruby using Rhomobile framework. I am trying to run rake command for android

```
rake run:android
```

but I'm getting following error

```
ERROR!!! API version is not found in installed Android SDK: 2.1
```

any hint on how to solve it?

also my rhobuild.yml files looks like

---

```
env: 
app: /Users/bhushan/rhodes_learn/employee_app
paths: 
android-ndk: /Users/bhushan/android-ndk-r7
java: /Library/Java/Home/bin
android: /Users/bhushan/android-sdk-macosx
4.6: 
  jde: 
  sim: 9000
  mds: 
cabwiz: 
4.2: 
  jde: 
  sim: 8100
  mds: 
 excludedirs: 
 bb: 
- public/js/iui
- public/js/jquery*
- public/jqtouch*
- public/js/prototype*
- public/css/iphone*
- public/iwebkit
- public/themes
- "**/jquery*.js"
- "**/*.db"
- public/images/android
- public/images/iphone
all: 
 - "**/.*.swo"
 - "**/.*.swn"
 - "**/.DS_Store"
android: 
build: 
symbianpath: platform/symbian
bb: 
bbsignpwd: somepasswordhere
bbpath: platform/bb
wmpath: platform/wm
androidpath: platform/android
wppath: platform/wp7
iphonepath: platform/iphone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the specified Version number in Rhodes Config file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the actual Android SDK Platform 2.1 installed? You should be able to check it from the SDK Manager tool that came with the Android SDK.

Also, if you've recently updated Rhodes (to 3.3.1, for example) you may need to re-run rhodes-setup and set-rhodes-sdk to update the locations of the tools

HTH,

Comment: Problem Solved. I had to change the specified Version number in Rhodes Config file.